# cocos2d scene deallocation and ccb nodes

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccscene

I have a simple `CCScene` containing only one node created from a CocosBuilder template with `[CCBReader nodeGraphWithFile:]` method.

So far, I did not release the ccb node in the `dealloc` method of the scene because I expected it to be autoreleased. But in the allocation profiler, I noticed that there is a memory leak if I push/pop the scene several times in the `CCDirector`.

This memory leak disappears if I actually `release` the node in the scene's `dealloc` method.

Why do I need to release the node though I didn't retain/init it ? Is there something I misunderstood ?

Answer (score 0):

What happens to the object created through this?

```
[CCBReader nodeGraphWithFile:]
```

If you assign it to a retain property, it will get retained; so you need to release it explicitly. E.g.:

```
self.nodeGraph = [CCBReader nodeGraphWithFile:...];
```

if `nodeGraph` is declared as a retain property, the autoreleased object created in `[CCBReader nodeGraphWithFile:]` will get retained by the property and you will need to release it in `dealloc`.

Contrast this to *not using* a property to keep a reference to the node object and add it directly to the node hierarchy:

```
[self addChildNode:[CCBReader nodeGraphWithFile:...]];
```

in this case, you would not need doing any explicit release, since you are not retaining yourself the object.

Comment: I do not assign it to a property. I just add it to the scene via `[self addChildNode:[CCBReader nodeGraphWithFile:...]];`. That's why I'm confused

Comment: so, which object are you sending the release to in the `dealloc` method?

Comment: `[[self.children objectAtIndex:0] release]`

Comment: that´s no good... it is pretty clear that a `release` is missing, otherwise sending it doubly would cause a crash. either cocos2d is not releasing its children (odd) or CocosBuilder is unduly retaining it too much... give a look at `CCBReader` sources...

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Actually I'm not sure I use the latest version of CCBReader. I'll let you know if I find the trick. Thanks anyway

Comment: It seems like the problem is cyclic retain cycle between the node and an animationManager. Someone has created an issue here:  https://github.com/cocos2d/CocosBuilder/issues/190